# Raku confusing postfix ,= operator behavior

Tags: operators, raku

This [raku documentation page](https://docs.perl6.org/language/operators#postfix_,=) says operator `,=` is supposed to concatenate

> the contents of the variable on the left hand side and the expression on the right hand side

in a class-dependent way. The documentation also provides an example with a `Hash` variable:

```
my %a = :11a, :22b;
%a ,= :33x;
say %a # OUTPUT: «{a => 11, b => 22, x => 33}␤»
```

This works for me, but when I try to do the same for an `Array` something confusing happens:

```
my @a = 1, 2;
@a ,= 3;
say @a
```

And the output is something like `(\Array_94393785458840 = [Array_94393785458840 3])`. I would expect however the result be `[1, 2, 3]`.

My question is: **Is this the expected behavior? And if so, what is the purpose of such an operation?**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
foo ,= bar
```

is short for

```
foo = foo, bar
```

So,

```
@a ,= 3
```

is short for:

```
@a = @a, 3;
```

During the Great List Refactor in 2015, the single argument rule became active everywhere.  Since the right hand side of the expression is *not* a single argument, the `@a`on the right hand side, will *not* get flattened.

So effectively, you're creating a self-referential Array, in which the first element refers to itself (which is what the `say` is trying to tell you).

For reasons I'm not too clear about anymore, the same does *not* apply to objects doing the Associative role.  So in that case, the `%a` *does* get flattened, thereby adding the given `Pair` to the Hash.

```
my %a = :11a, :22b;
%a = %a, :33x;
say %a # OUTPUT: «{a => 11, b => 22, x => 33}␤»
```

To get back to your question: in the case of an Array, I don't think there is much use for the `,=` operation.  Before the Great List Refactor, it may have done what you expected.  But it would have been inconsistent with other situations, and consistency was deemed more important (because before the Great List Refactor, when something would flatten and when not, was rather arbitrary and many times a source of WAT instead of DWIM).

Answer (score 2):

For those less familiar with Raku, it is easy to flatten any Array with a slip ‘|’ like so:

```perl
@a = |@a, :33;
```

(at the cost of an extra operator)

Answer (score 0):

Array operations are available instead (`push`, `pop`, `shift`, `unshift`):

In the Raku REPL:

```perl
> my @a = 1, 2;
[1 2]
> say @a;
[1 2]
```

```perl
> @a .push: 3;
[1 2 3]
> say @a;
[1 2 3]
>
```

Confusingly, operations like `.push` and `.=push` give the same result, so the latter is dis-favored:

```perl
> @a .=push: 4;
[1 2 3 4]
> say @a;
[1 2 3 4]
>
```

The above extant "`,=`" workarounds are for Arrays. AFAIK no cognate "`,=`" workaround exists for Lists (e.g. starting from `my $b = 1, 2;`).